# How to run js to get data when page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, mysql

I want the page to run the form.js and load the data from read.php when the page is loaded. And refresh the table automatically every few seconds instead of clicking the refresh button. Is this possible and how can I accomplish this?

```
// index.html
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/dashboard/form.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="read.php" method="POST">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Refresh</button>
    </form>
    <table class="table" id="tableRefresh">
        // table content
    </table>
  </body>

// form.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("form").submit(function loadDetails (event) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "read.php",
            dataType: "json",
        }).done(function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.success) {
                $("#tableRefresh").html(
                    // edit table content
                )
            }
        });
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove the <form> and associated JS code and put the `$.ajax` call into a `setInterval` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can optimize the form.js code file to fetch/refresh data automatically at a specified interval of time as below:

```
function loadData() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "read.php",
    dataType: "json",
  }).done(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    if (data.success) {
      $("#tableRefresh").html(
        // edit table content
      )
    }
  });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(loadData, 10000); // refresh data every 10 secs
});
```